# What are "Random Transactions" in IOTA Peer Manager?

Tags: iri-node

See highlighted item in the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [looking at the code](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/501e9493bc0cbd1ef1b3e0df6da39efb8ef4083d/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java?line=419#L419), you can see that sometimes a neighbor may ask for a random tip and in this case your own node may reply to this request (under the condition that your own node have at least one pending transaction request).

The "random transactions" amount is the number of "random tips" that your node send to this particular neighbor.

Here is the relevant part of the code :

```
//retrieve requested transaction


if (requestedHash.equals(Hash.NULL_HASH)) {
    //Random Tip Request
    try {
        if (transactionRequester.numberOfTransactionsToRequest() > 0 && rnd.nextDouble() < P_REPLY_RANDOM_TIP) {
            neighbor.incRandomTransactionRequests();
            transactionPointer = getRandomTipPointer();
            transactionViewModel = TransactionViewModel.fromHash(tangle, transactionPointer);
        } else {
            //no tx to request, so no random tip will be sent as a reply.
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error getting random tip.", e);
    }
}
```